# Cause of distal convergence in anterior teeth

Tags: dentistry, oral-health, anatomy

In anterior teeth, the distal side of the incisal edge is more curved than the mesial side. Furthermore, the incisal edge slopes distally, and the cingulum twists towards the distal side. Why does this occur? Is it because of mastication, is it another reason, or does it just happen?

Comment: What are the results of your own research so far?

Comment: I have been unable to find anything so far